# Top down acceleration and deceleration using quartic easing curve

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I've tried to figure out a good way to do this for a while now and decided I would bite the bullet and ask.

I've been moving my character around using this code snippet:

```
Vector2 desiredVelocity = input.movementAxis * Mathf.Max(stats.movementSpeed.Value, 0f);

float maxSpeedChange;
if (input.movementAxis != Vector2.zero)
    maxSpeedChange = acceleration;
else
    maxSpeedChange = deceleration;

velocity.x = Mathf.MoveTowards(velocity.x, desiredVelocity.x, maxSpeedChange);
velocity.y = Mathf.MoveTowards(velocity.y, desiredVelocity.y, maxSpeedChange);
```

It uses Unity's MoveTowards function to cause the character to accelerate and decelerate. However, MoveTowards is built off of Lerp, and I don't want to use a basic Lerp function for the acceleration curve. I want to try a quartic curve and see how that feels but I have no idea how to integrate that into this setup. Is there some way I could modify my code to allow for this? Ideally I don't want any more variables outside this scope if it's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using [`LerpUnclamped`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.LerpUnclamped.html) and clamp yourself the speed change?

Comment: have you considered e.g. [Mathf.SmoothDamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html)? Note btw that in your case you could directly use [`Vector2.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) and [`Vector2.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SmoothDamp.html) ;)